I want to Find data in Sequelize that createdAt and UpdateAt same Consider only date Not date time
    const StudentAssessmentTransaction = sequelize.define(
      "studentAssessmentTransaction",
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        status: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          defaultValue: "Pending",
          validate: {
            isIn: {
              args: [["Pending", "Success"]],
              msg: "Type must be either 'Pending' or 'Success'",
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        paranoid: true,
      }
    );


I want to find data that createdAt and UpdateAt same Consider Only date not date time
I have try multiple Things but not get data
Tried Things
    where: { [Op.eq]: [ fn('DATE', col('createdAt')), fn('DATE', col('updatedAt'))] } 

    [Op.eq]: literal("DATE(studentAssessmentTransaction.createdAt) = DATE(studentAssessmentTransaction.updatedAt)")


I have try Different Way and Finally I found this answer


where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          Sequelize.where(
            fn("DATE", col("createdAt")),
            Op.eq,
            fn("DATE", col("updatedAt"))
          ),
        ],
      },



Using this We can find data that createdAt and updatedAt the same And this considers only date in comparison
